# CvSVM(const CvSVM&)’ is private

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

while using the line ...

```
map<string,CvSVM> classes_classifiers;
classes_classifiers.insert(pair<string,CvSVM>(class_,CvSVM()));
```

when i am colpiling it i am getting the error...

> In file included from predict.cpp:10:0:
>   /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_pair.h: In instantiation of ‘std::pair<_T1, >_T2>::pair(const _T1&, const _T2&) [with _T1 = std::basic_string; _T2 = CvSVM]’:
>   predict.cpp:99:64:   required from here
>   /usr/local/include/opencv2/ml/ml.hpp:553:5: error: ‘CvSVM::CvSVM(const CvSVM&)’ is private
>   In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/utility:72:0,
>                   from /usr/include/c++/4.7/algorithm:61,
>                   from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:56,
>                   from /usr/local/include/opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp:46,
>                   from predict.cpp:4:
>   /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:105:31: error: within this context

can any one please tell how can solve this . I am beginner and i making this project which distinguishes between differebt sets of images.
i have rained my SVM and have saved data for images of different class in different files. Now i need to predict.
please help
thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error means the copy constructor of the `CvSVM` class is private; therefore you simply can't write valid code that requires a `CvSVM` object to be copied. It follows that you can't copy a class containing a `CvSVM` object, either, such as a pair. And calling `map::insert` makes a copy.

The first thing you might want to do is check whether there is a newer version of the library that supports C++11. It's quite likely that the `CvSVM` class can be moved even if it can't be copied. If so, this code ought to compile without modification against a newer version.

If not, but *you* have C++11 support, you can have the object constructed directly in a container, so that it doesn't need to be copied *or* moved at all. However, this is a bit tricky when the container is a map, since the value you have to construct is actually a *pair* whose *second* element is a `CvSVM`. This is how you do it:

```
classes_classifiers.emplace(piecewise_construct, make_tuple(class_), make_tuple());
```

Another possibility, if you have C++11 support, is to store `unique_ptr<CvSVM>` objects in your map instead of the `CvSVM` objects themselves. The use of `unique_ptr` guarantees that when you remove an element from the map, the object is `delete`d:

```
map<string,unique_ptr<CvSVM>> classes_classifiers;
classes_classifiers.insert(make_pair(class_, unique_ptr<CvSVM>(new CvSVM())));
```

If you don't have C++11 support, your only option is to store raw pointers to `CvSVM` in your map. This is less than optimal because it requires you to `delete` each pointer before erasing it from the map, otherwise you'll leak memory.

Comment: and is make_pair a function of stl_pair.cpp ??

Comment: `make_pair` is defined in the `<utility>` header, which is the same header you have to include in order to use pairs anyway. `unique_ptr` can be used like a normal pointer, but it can't be copied, and it automatically deletes its referrent when it's destroyed.

Comment: when i am compiling with `map<string,unique_ptr<CvSVM>> classes_classifiers;` . i am getting error, saying unique_ptr is not defined.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` is defined in the `<memory>` header

Comment: sir i am using `#include <memory> and still getting ‘unique_ptr’ `was not declared in this scope`. what should i do now.

Comment: Make sure you have C++11 support turned on with `-std=c++0x` or `-std=c++11`